# Is this set a basis of $F_{3}^{1*3}$ or $F_{2}^{1*3}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, residue-calculus, change-of-basis

Is this set a basis of $F_{3}^{1*3}$ or $F_{2}^{1*3}?$:

{0,1,1),(1,0,1),(1,1,0)}

This was a question on my last quiz and I decided that it was a basis for $F_{2}^{1*3}$, because there are only 1 and 0. But the answer had to be $F_{3}^{1*3}$ Can someone help me understand why it was a basis of residue field 3 instead of 2?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  What do you get if you add the first two vectors in $F_2$?

Comment: Ohhh, it would then be lineary dependent! A pitty I proved linear independency out of context! But now I understand it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though {$(0,1,1),(1,0,1),(1,1,0)$} could be a collection of vectors over $F_2$,

it is not a basis for a three-dimensional space over $F_2,$

because these three vectors are not linearly independent over $F_2$,

because, over $F_2, (1,1,0)=(0,1,1)+(1,0,1).$

---

They are linearly independent over $F_3$, because if $a_1(0,1,1)+a_2(1,0,1)+a_3(1,1,0)=(0,0,0),$

where $a_1,a_2,a_3\in F_3,$ then $(a_2+a_3, a_1+a_3, a_1+a_2)=(0,0,0)$.

The difference of the third and first components implies $a_1-a_3=0$;

combining this with the second component $a_1+a_3=0$ means $2a_1=0$,

which implies $a_1=0$ in fields not of characteristic $2$ such as $F_3$.

From $a_1=0$ and $a_1+a_3=a_1+a_2=0,$ it follows that $a_2=a_3=0$ too.